# Ember - Reading currentUser from JSON and using it to create currentUser and using that in another model record

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

My app has comments and here I am attempting to save a comment along with details of the current user that made the comment.

In the first instance I'm just trying to look up a valid user record and do it explicitly.

```
# comments.js.coffee

App.CommentsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    createComment: ->
      comment = @store.createRecord('comment')
      comment.set('body','hope eternally')
      comment.set('section', @get('model'))
      user = @store.find('user', 3)
      comment.set('user', user)
      comment.save()
```

This returns an error as the user field is not being set.

IRC #emberjs peeps helped me understand that @store.find is asyncronous and I'll need to deal with promises to make this work.

Here's most of my code, I even played with making a separate CurrentUserController and giving it it's own Adapter, but that's not completed, but you can see my code in the store.

```
# models/comment.js.coffee

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend
  body: DS.attr('string')
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  created_at: DS.attr('date')
  section: DS.belongsTo('section')
```

User model

```
# models/user.js.coffee

App.User = DS.Model.extend
  email: DS.attr('string')
```

Comments route

```
# routes/comments.js.coffee
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  currentUser: ''

  activate:   -> 
    @controllerFor('plan').set 'editMode', true
    window.scrollTo(0,97)
    @set('currentUser', @store.find('user',3))

  deactivate: -> 
    @controllerFor('plan').set 'editMode', false
```

And the store..

```
# store.js.coffee

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api/v1'

App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend
    headers: (->
        "X-CSRF-Token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    ).property().volatile()

App.CurrentUserAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
    pathForType: "/sessions/current"
```

and the router..

```
# router.js.coffee

App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'plans', path: '/', ->
    @resource 'plan', path: 'plans/:id', ->
        @route 'edit'
        @resource 'section', path: 'sections/:section_id', ->
            @route 'edit'
                @resource 'comments', path: 'comments'
```

**[Edit 1: Revised controller and route]**
With a stack of help from @lauren I've played with her code down to this.

```
# comments_controller.js.coffee

App.CommentsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: 'plan'
  editMode: true

  actions:
    saveComment: ->
      @get('model').save()
      .then -> 
        @get('section.comments')
      .then (comments) ->
        comments.pushObject comment
        true
      .catch (error) -> console.debug error

    close: ->
      @transitionToRoute('plan.index')
```

and here is the revised router

```
# comments_route.js.coffee

App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  activate:   -> 
    @controllerFor('plan').set 'editMode', true
    window.scrollTo(0,97)

  deactivate: -> 
    @controllerFor('plan').set 'editMode', false

  model: ->
    Em.RSVP.hash
        section:  @modelFor 'section',
        user:     @store.find 'user', 3
        model:      @store.createRecord 'comment'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you didn't set the user properly on the comments controller and route. In your route, you should be setting those properties on the `model` hook, not `activate`.

In my gist below, I setup the route's model to take a hash of an empty comment (not saved) and your user record. Then I set the `model` and `user` property on the controller in the `setupController` hook.

Try this - https://gist.github.com/poteto/8023b0c360e7af40672a